# Associative property of cardinal adjectives

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

Would you say, *e.g.*, 'ten fingers and toes' to convey ten of each, or 'twenty fingers and toes' to convey their total?

Does the implied number change if the items are not analogous (*e.g.*, 'fingers and toes'), but instead wholly unrelated (*e.g.*, 'fingers and flowers')?

I did look at an ngram of the two phrases in my first example, but it doesn’t seem so clear cut—and a quick sampling of the corpus does not necessarily reflect proper grammatical usage, which is what I would like to understand.

[image]

And, yes, I realize saying 'ten fingers and ten toes' would improve clarity.

Comment: Since you realize that deleting the  number from the second conjoined noun phrase loses clarity, you should realize that _ten fingers and toes/flowers_ is intrinsically ambiguous and that there are therefore no rules for interpreting what such sentences mean. Deleting material always loses information, and that usually increases ambiguity. If you want clarity, write clearly and don't depend on the reader to guess what you mean.

Comment: If you wanted to emphasise the fact that there were twenty, then a rewording such as "a total of twenty fingers and toes" or "fingers and toes totalling twenty" might work.

Comment: Also note that polling Google NGrams is not a solution to your problem. Your search terms are not necessarily used in the same contexts, and so your results will be questionable.

Comment: Actually, around 1980 parents began cutting off the little fingers and toes of their kids, so they would learn to count in octal or hexadecimal.

Comment: Note that 'ten fingers and toes' also has the possible meaning 'Umpteen toes and ten fingers'.

Answer (score 1):

> Ten fingers and ten toes

is the best solution.

**There is no clear answer to a lesser solution** because it would be subject to the assumptions a particular reader might make.

Why would you pursue a lesser solution anyway?

Comment: Yep, you can't just wish away ambiguity, you have to clarify things to eliminate it.